# How to change page orientation of PDF? (Ghostscript or PostScript solution needed)

Tags: pdf, postscript, ghostscript

Given a PDF document, how do I change individual page orientation?

I'm using latest version of Ghostscript.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Why do you ***require*** usage of Ghostscript? Would it be acceptable to use another Free, Open Source Software tool running on the commandline, such as `pdftk`?

Anyway, here is how to rotate pages with Ghostscript. However, this may not work for your intentions, because you cannot **force** a certain orientation for an individual page only. It relies on an internal Ghostscript algorithm that tries to rotate pages automatically, depending on the flow of text inside the PDFs:
* `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`  -- retains orientation of each page;
* `-dAutoRotatePages=/All`  -- rotates all pages (or none) depending on a kind of "majority decision";
* `-dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage` -- auto-rotates pages individually.

Add one of these to the Ghostscript commandline you're using.

If there is ***no*** text on a page (or if there is an automatic page rotation set to `/None`), then Ghostscript uses the `setpagedevice` settings. You can pass such `setpagedevice` parameters on the Ghostscript commandline using the `-c` switch like this:
* `-c "<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *landscape* orientation;
* `-c "<</Orientation 0>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *portrait* orientation;
* `-c "<</Orientation 2>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *upside down* orientation;
* `-c "<</Orientation 1>> setpagedevice"` -- sets *seascape* orientation.

Probably you need to set the orientation for each page when *extracting* the pages. I don't think it would work when merging them back to the unified document (I have never tested this).

In any case, I'd recommend to look at `pdftk` too (which is also available for Windows). It is a commandline tool that can rotate pages from PDFs, and much more. Easier to use than Ghostscript for your stated purpose, and much faster as well. Especially, it can rotate individual pages inside a PDF document, leaving the other pages untouched. ***Example:***

```
pdftk A=in.pdf           \
  cat A1-3 A4west A5-end \
  output out.pdf
```

This command will output pages 1, 2 and 3 as well as pages 5, 6, ... last un-rotated, but will rotate page 4 by 90 degrees (so the page header faces to the "west"). <sub>(However, be aware that this command can lead to unexpected results, depending on the original orientation of your input pages: You should check the orientation of all pages of your input PDF by running `pdfinfo -l 1000 input.pdf` and then check for the value of the `rot` output: if you see values different from `0`, like `90`, `180` and `270`, these pages are already pre-rotated...)</sub>

See here for more details: http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/ .

Comment: Hi pipitas, I'm trying this but it's not working: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="page2rot.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dEPSCrop -c "<</Orientation 0>> setpagedevice" -f "page2.pdf" -c quit` can you see an issue with this?

Comment: @Pureferret: without access to your *"page2.pdf"* input PDF I cannot look at the issue....

Comment: I mean 'Would the specific .pdf file change things'

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I started using ghostscript for various things after seeing pdftk freeze on some input files.

Comment: @mirabilos: Ok, I've added an example now. (*Does this answer now earn your upvote?* :)   If you look at other answers of mine, usually I add examples to all the command line tools I recommend...

Comment: Do any of you know how to go back to the previous page during viewing ?

Comment: used to be a free feature

Answer (score 4):

Nothing else than -dNORANGEPAGESIZE worked perfectly for me.

Comment: you must elaborate more on the answer!

Comment: I have no idea why but this fixed it for me too combined with -dAutoRotatePages=/All and made the page rotate automatically correctly

Comment: Thanks all! Thisi work: -dAutoRotatePages=/All -dNORANGEPAGESIZE

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I tried several different combinations of input arguments and the only one that worked for me was the combination of these two:

```
"-dNORANGEPAGESIZE", 
"-dAutoRotatePages=/All",
```

Comment: My original file was a table full of numbers, in Landscape orientation. And all I tried printed this table, partly, in Portrait mode. Till I used the above combination and then I had my table fully fit to A4 page in Landscape mode.