# convert pdf page size from A3 to A4 in Python in Windows

Tags: python, imagemagick, ghostscript

How can I convert an A3 pdf to A4 pdf in python. I need a way that can be applied in all platforms-Windows, Mac and Linux.
So something like this maybe:

```
import os
os.system(' command to convert A3 to A4 pdf ')
```

So far I found many ways to do it in Linux from here: [Need to Programmatically Convert PDF Paper Size (e.g. US-Letter to A4) in Python (or command line)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36950487/need-to-programmatically-convert-pdf-paper-size-e-g-us-letter-to-a4-in-python)

I think it can be done via ImageMagick also(http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page) but I am not sure how to implement it correctly.
I tried:

```
pdf_folder = os.listdir(infolder)
pdf_files = [_ for _ in pdf_folder if _[-4:] == ".pdf"]
print("Available PDFs:\n")
for pdffile in pdf_files:
    print(pdffile)
    convert  -page a4 pdffile pdffile
```

But this gives a invalid syntax error

Comment: Imagemagick will rasterize your PDF if it was a vector file. It will not produce a new vector file. If that is OK, then `convert A3.pdf -resize 595x842 A4.pdf` If on the IM 7.0.10.35 then `magick A3.pdf -resize "%[papersize:A4]" A4.pdf`

Comment: the convert command is giving me an error `Invalid Parameter - -resize` and the magick command is giving me the error `magick: unknown image property "%[papersize:A4]" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/4081.
magick: invalid argument for option '-resize' '' at CLI arg 2 @ error/operation.c/CLISimpleOperatorImage/3221.`

Comment: That argument is not available in IM 6 and only available in the most current version of IM 7 --- 7.0.10.35

Comment: I have ImageMagick 7.0.10-33 installed.

Comment: You will need to upgrade to use [papersize:A4]  It needs 7.0.10.35